# Javascript Member Functions Out of Scope

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I have a class that creates an anchor object. When the user clicks on the anchor I want it to run a function from the parent class.

```
function n()
{
    var make = function()
    {
        ...

        var a = document.createElement('a');    
        a.innerHTML = 'Add';
        //this next line does not work, it returns the error: 
        //"this.add_button is not a function"
        a.onclick = function() { this.add_button(); }                                               

        ...
    }

    var add_button = function()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you just need to get rid of the "this." in front of add_button()

You are declaring add_button as a local variable (or private in the weird way that javascript classes work), so it isn't actually a member of "this".

Just use:

```
a.onclick = function(){add_button();}
```

Comment: +1. Hopefully he doesn't need the value of that this pointer inside add_button, but this is a good star.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is that `this` in the context of the `onclick` function is not the same as `this` in the context of the `n` function/"class". If you want `this` within the function to be equivalent to `this` from the class, you need to **bind** `this` to the function.

Binding is a way of changing the scope of a function -- essentially if you bind to a function, you are replacing the `this` variable to point to something else. You can read more about binding in Javascript in [this alternateidea article](http://alternateidea.com/blog/articles/2007/7/18/javascript-scope-and-binding).

If you were using [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org), for example, you could do something like:

```
function n()
{
    var make = function()
    {
        ...
        a.onclick = function() { this.add_button() }.bind(this);
        ...
    }
}
```

Which would bind class `n`'s `this` to the onclick function, thus giving the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

The "this" in "this.add_button();" is actually referring to the anchor element itself which has no "add_button()" function, if I'm not mistaken.

Perhaps this would work:

```
a.onclick = function() { n.add_button(); }
```